# How to keep global vis.js options in a single file?

Tags: vis.js

Is is possible to store global vis.js options for a site in one place rather than repeat them on every page? I can't find any example how to do that in vis.js documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`options` variable IS global so it can be put in a separate file and referenced on each page.